# Android: How to Prevent Down Press animation of a button when scrolling a list?

Tags: android, scroll, android-imageview

So i have an `ImageView` that I want to use as a button. When I press this button it scales a little bit down and when i release it, the button scales back to original size.

To do this I attach an `onTouchListener` to the image:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Animation anim;
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Scale down ImageView when finger is down
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.poster_scale_down);
            v.startAnimation(anim);
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Scale up ImageView when finger is up
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.poster_scale_normal);
            v.startAnimation(anim);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
             // Scale up ImageView when action is canceled
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.poster_scale_normal);
            v.startAnimation(anim);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a series of these `ImageViews` in a `RecyclerView`. So when I am scrolling, it will trigger the `ACTION_DOWN` pressed animation of where my finger was. This is really annoying!

How do I prevent this? Is there a better way to add an animation as a selector for an ImageView?

**EDIT WITH A SORT OF WORKAROUND:**

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            v.clearAnimation();
            break;
```

When you scroll it will cancel your current touch on the list item, so just clear the animation. This isn't perfect because it will still cause the animation to start just slightly if you're not swiping fast enough

Answer (score 0):

Simply maintain the state with a variable by yourself.
E.g. when first press down, set the variable to true, if the variable is true, do not perform the animation. When it is released, set the variable to false.